# Grails with YUI table example

Tags: grails, yui

Does anyone have an example using the table object in YUI library.  More specifically, I'd like to dynamically load it from JSON or SQL?

http://www.grails.org/YUI+Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this example.  Will be trying it out this weekend.  Looks like exactly what I was looking for.

http://marceloverdijk.blogspot.com/2008/06/grails-yui-datatable-example.html

Answer (score 0):

From the YUI documentation: [DataTable examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/index.html). In particular, here's [an example using JSON and XmlHttpRequest](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_xhrjson.html).